# Difference between which and them

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce
>   works of art from the ice, many of **which/them** can be found in the
>   rooms.

Which one is correct? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both.

"Many of **them** can be found in the rooms." is an independent clause and needs to be separated by a semi-colon or a full stop/period:

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice; many of them can be found in the rooms. *or*
>
> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice. Many of them can be found in the rooms.

If you want to use "which," then you need a comma to separate the two sentences. This is because by using "which," you are creating a dependent clause, but the one which is non-essential, i.e., you can remove this part without affecting the meaning of the original sentence:

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice.
>
> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice, many of which can be found in the rooms.

If you want to convey that only the artists are to be found in the room, use "whom" instead of "which/them" to kill the ambiguity.

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice, many of whom can be found in the rooms.

Answer (score 4):

With "them", it would be a run-on sentence: two independent clauses without a conjunction between them. If they are made into separate sentences, or semi-separated by a semi-colon (as commenters suggest) then it would be grammatical (though, ambiguous as to what "them" referred back to).

With "which", the second clause becomes a relative clause, and the sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice, many of them can be found in the rooms.

What's odd with this sentence? Well, what will I find in the rooms? The works of art? or will I find the world-famous artists? I'm not sure. It can be either of them.

*'Them'* can refer to the artists as well as their works. On the other hand, if you had used *'which'*,

> Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice, many of **which** can be found in the rooms.

It becomes very clear what you'll find in the room. So I suggest you use **'which'** instead of **'them'**.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I don't think the version with _them_ is grammatical unless you change the comma to a semi-colon.

Comment: @J.R., okay, I'll edit out that part.

Comment: You were on the right track. I think this would be fine: _Each year, world-famous artists are invited to design and produce works of art from the ice; many of them can be found at the convention_. That would mean many of the invited artists accept the invitation. But I think it would be awkward to be talking about the artists in the O.P.'s original sentence.

Comment: A semi-colon changes the entire layout of the sentence. But the OP has used a comma. I agree that by replacing the comma with a semi-colon, you could use *'them'* without any doubt on what is being referred by the speaker. But when the comma is used, doesn't *'them'* sound awkward? Or is it just me?